# Send Form for create with AJAX and Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel-5.1

I'm developing an application with Laravel 5.1 and I have a problem when sending ajax petition I have the next code:

View for Create:

```
{!!Form::open()!!}

    <div class="form-group">
   {!!Form::label('genero','Genre:')!!}
   {!!Form::text('genre',null,['id'=> 'genre','class'=>'form-control'])!!}
    </div>

    {!!link_to('#', $title = 'Create', $attributes = ['id'=> 'create','class'=>'btn btn-primary'], $secure = null)!!}
{!!Form::close()!!}
```

Ajax Petition:

```
$("#create").click(function(){
 var genre = $("#genre").val();
 var route = "http://localhost:8000/genre";
 $.ajax({
   url: route,
   type: 'POST',
   dataType: 'json'
   data: {genre : genre}
  });
})
```

In my Routes:

```
Route::resource('genre','GenreController');
```

But when send the petition I have the next error:

```
POST http://localhost:8000/genre 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

Thanks.

Comment: Check your php error log.  The reason for the error will be in there most likely

Comment: into the console (Preview) I have the next error : TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 53:

Comment: TokenMismatch can be fixed by adding the header to your ajax post method. If you are creating the javascript in the view you can put the value in the ajax parameter. `headers: { 'X-XSRF-TOKEN': {{ Session::token() }} } `

Comment: This answer may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28500525/laravel-5-csrf-global-token-hidden-field-for-all-forms-in-a-page

Comment: I add into my view the token : {!! Form::token() !!} and add the headers into my petition ajax headers: {   'X-XSRF-Token': $('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content') } but i have the same error u.u

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was the next code:

```
$("#registro").click(function(){
var data = $("#genre").val();
var route = "http://localhost:8000/genre";
var token = document.getElementById('token').value

$.ajax({
  url: route,
  headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': token},
  type: 'POST',
  dataType: 'json',
  data: {data : data}
 });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

In default template , add meta tag

```
<meta name="_token" content="{!! csrf_token() !!}"/>
```

Then add script code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$.ajaxSetup({
headers: { 'X-CSRF-Token' : $('meta[name=_token]').attr('content') }
});
</script>
```

Then you can use ajax call...as normal