# Load text field using ajax in Laravel

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel-5.1, laravel-blade

I am trying to load employee name in a employee text field after selecting employee id from another select field.

**Route:**

```
post('driver','SalaryController@driver');
```

**Controller:**

```
public function driver($eid)
{
    $driver = Employee::all()->where('eid',$eid)->pluck('name');
    return $driver;
}
```

**Blade:**

```
{!! Form::open(['action'=>'SalaryController@pay','method'=>'post','class'=>'form-horizontal']) !!}
<div class="col-md-12 d-section">
    <div class="col-md-6"> {{-- Left hand side --}}
        <div class="form-group"> {{-- Date --}}
            {!! Form::label('date','Date:',['class'=>'control-label col-sm-3']) !!}
            <div class="col-sm-9">
                {!! Form::text('date',null,['class'=>'form-control datetimepicker']) !!}
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group"> {{-- eid --}}
            {!! Form::label('eid','ID:',['class'=>'control-label col-sm-3']) !!}
            <div class="col-sm-9">
                {!! Form::select('eid',$repository->employees(),null,['class'=>'form-control','id'=>'eid']) !!}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6"> {{-- Right hand side --}}
        <div class="form-group"> {{-- Month --}}
            {!! Form::label('month','Month:',['class'=>'control-label col-sm-3']) !!}
            <div class="col-sm-9">
                {!! Form::select('month',$repository->months(),null,['class'=>'form-control']) !!}
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group"> {{-- name --}}
            {!! Form::label('name','Name:',['class'=>'control-label col-sm-3']) !!}
            <div class="col-sm-9">
                {!! Form::text('name',null,['class'=>'form-control','id'=>'name']) !!}
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group"> {{-- Paying --}}
            {!! Form::label('paid','Paying',['class'=>'control-label col-sm-3']) !!}
            <div class="col-sm-9">
                {!! Form::text('paid',null,['class'=>'form-control']) !!}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-12 d-section text-center">
    {!! Form::submit('PAY',['class'=>'btn btn-success','name'=>'advance']) !!}
    {!! Form::reset('RESET',['class'=>'btn btn-warning']) !!}
    <a href="{{ action('SalaryController@index') }}" role="button" class="btn btn-danger">CANCEL</a>
</div>
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

**Ajax:**

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#eid').change(function(){
            var eid = $(this).val();
            var csrf = $('#csrf').val();
            var name = $('#name').val();
            $.ajax({
                URL : 'driver',
                data : {driver:eid,_token:csrf},
                type : 'post'
            }).done(function(e){
                name.html(e)
            })
        })
    })
</script>
```

The code is not working. I tested with `firebug`. After select employee id it shows the following error

> **POST http://localhost/zamzam/advance** *500 Internal Server Error 1.05s* jquery.min.js (line 5)

**EDIT**

Here is the error log from **storage\log\laravel.log**

```
[2016-01-22 12:36:56] local.ERROR: exception 'Illuminate\Session\TokenMismatchException' in D:\xampp\htdocs\zamzam\root\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken.php:53
Stack trace:
#0 [internal function]: Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#1 D:\xampp\htdocs\zamzam\root\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(124): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#2 D:\xampp\htdocs\zamzam\root\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession.php(54): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#3 [internal function]: Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#4 D:\xampp\htdocs\zamzam\root\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(124): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#5 D:\xampp\htdocs\zamzam\root\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession.php(62): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#6 [internal function]: Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#7 D:\xampp\htdocs\zamzam\root\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(124): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#8 D:\xampp\htdocs\zamzam\root\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php(37): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#9 [internal function]: Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#10 D:\xampp\htdocs\zamzam\root\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(124): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#11 D:\xampp\htdocs\zamzam\root\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\EncryptCookies.php(59): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#12 [internal function]: Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\EncryptCookies->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#13 D:\xampp\htdocs\zamzam\root\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(124): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#14 D:\xampp\htdocs\zamzam\root\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode.php(42): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#15 [internal function]: Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#16 D:\xampp\htdocs\zamzam\root\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(124): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#17 [internal function]: Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#18 D:\xampp\htdocs\zamzam\root\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(103): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#19 D:\xampp\htdocs\zamzam\root\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel.php(122): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
#20 D:\xampp\htdocs\zamzam\root\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel.php(87): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#21 D:\xampp\htdocs\zamzam\index.php(54): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#22 {main}
```

Comment: As long as the server returns an internal error, you should paste the error log.

Comment: @Kdecherf The error is showing in `firebug`. Where from I get the error log?

Comment: Check the log of your webserver (or the log of Laravel which is, by default, stored in storage/logs)

Comment: Try `dd($eid)` before all in your controller.

Comment: @Kdecherf I have shared the error log.

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki I tried but nothing happened for `dd($eid)`. When I saw in `post` tab in `firebug` it shows the correct id which I have selected.

Comment: TokenMismatchException shows that there is an issue with the CSRF token. Are you sure that the token is actually sent?

Comment: There is a similar issue here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31416965/send-form-for-create-with-ajax-and-laravel-5-1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I solved it. There were many mistakes in my code. Trying to list them and describe one by one. It might helps others in future.

**Mistakes:**

1. _token mismatch exception
2. Using wrong parameter in controller
3. Wrong ajax code

**1. _token mismatch exception:** As I am using Laravel Blade template in html form, I have `_token` field by default. But it has no `id` or `class`. So, I added a `_token` field by myself with `id` named `token`.

```
<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}" id="token"/>
```

It's keep the original one too both of them have same values.

**2. Using wrong parameter in controller:** I was trying to use `$eid` as parameter. I should used `Request` facade and `$request` service container to inject instances of current http request to controller's method. I needed to inject the employee id (eid) in method, So I change my controller code to this

```
public function driver(Request $request)
{
    $eid = $request->get('eid'); //get the value of eid from "data : {eid:eid,_token:csrf},"
    $driver = Employee::all()->where('eid',$eid)->pluck('name');
    return $driver;
}
```

**3. Wrong ajax code:** I passed the `middlware` with `token` value, get the value of `eid` (employee id), now need to display the employee name in name field. After successfully connect to the database using `ajax`, It is just a simple `jquery` code to display a value in a text field. Here is my ajax code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#eid').change(function(){
        var eid = $(this).val();
        var csrf = $('#token').val();
        $.ajax({
            url : 'driver',
            data : {eid:eid,_token:csrf},
            type : 'post'
        }).success(function(e){
            $('#name').val(e)
        })
    })
})
```

**Route** remains intact as it was

```
post('driver','SalaryController@driver');
```