# How to pass laravel CSRF token value to vue

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-5.3

I have this form where the user should only type text inside a text area:

```
            <form action="#" v-on:submit="postStatus">{{-- Name of the method in Vue.js --}}
                <div class="form-group">
                    <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" maxlength="140" autofocus placeholder="What are you upto?" required v-model="post"></textarea>
                </div>
                <input type="submit" value="Post" class="form-control btn btn-info">

                {{ csrf_field() }}

            </form>
```

Then, I have this script code where I am using vue.js with ajax in order to pass that text into a controller and eventually save it into the database:

```
//when we actually submit the form, we want to catch the action
    new Vue({
        el      : '#timeline',
        data    :   {
            post    : '',
        },
        http    :   {
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-Token': $('meta[name=_token]').attr('content')
            }
        },
        methods : {
            postStatus : function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                console.log('Posted: '+this.post+ '. Token: '+this.token);
                $.ajax({
                    url         :   '/posts',
                    type        :   'post',
                    dataType    :   'json',
                    data        :   {
                        'body'  :   this.post,
                    }
                });
            }
        },
    });
```

However, this doesn't work so far, since there's this token mismatch exception. I don't know how to make it work. How to pass this token value to the controller. I have tried the following:

1) inside the form, I have added a vue name to the token:

```
<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="YzXAnwBñC7qPK9kg7MGGIUzznEOCi2dTnG9h9çpB" v-model="token">
```

2) I have tried to pass this token value into the vue:

```
//when we actually submit the form, we want to catch the action
    new Vue({
        el      : '#timeline',
        data    :   {
            post    : '',
            token   : '',
        },
        methods : {
            postStatus : function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                console.log('Posted: '+this.post+ '. Token: '+this.token);
                $.ajax({
                    url         :   '/posts',
                    type        :   'post',
                    dataType    :   'json',
                    data        :   {
                        'body'  :   this.post,
                        '_token':   this.token,
                    }
                });
            }
        },
    });
```

... but in the console, vue doesn't even catch it :(

This leads me to the following error:

> TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 68:

How do I fix it? Any ideas?

Comment: Put an @ symbol.... @{{ csrf_field() }}

Comment: @tam It makes strange things. The form, for example, no longer appears if I put the `@`

Comment: Without the @, when u inspect the DOM do you see the csrf field?

Comment: @tam Yes, I do see `<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="0NjpnvRbsYPNL3V8gwY40P2HMQMMoqG1noH9eqQ6">` which is the output from `{{ csrf_field() }}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved it thanks to these two answers:

1) First I read [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28500672/1883256), which led me to

2) This [second one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28418032/1883256).

So, in my form I keep this:

`{{ csrf_field() }}`

And inside the js file I only add the following (outside and above the Vue instance):

`var csrf_token = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');`

So the whole js code is:

```
var csrf_token = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');
    /*Event handling within vue*/
    //when we actually submit the form, we want to catch the action
    new Vue({
        el      : '#timeline',
        data    :   {
            post    : '',
            token   : csrf_token,
        },
        methods : {
            postStatus : function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                console.log('Posted: '+this.post+ '. Token: '+this.token);
                $.ajax({
                    url         :   '/posts',
                    type        :   'post',
                    dataType    :   'json',
                    data        :   {
                        'body'  :   this.post,
                        '_token':   this.token,
                    }
                });
            }
        },
    });
```

Comment: This doesn't work if you aren't serving any HTML from Laravel in the first place.

Answer (score 53):

`Very Easy Solution`
Just add a **hidden field** inside the form. An Example

```
<form id="logout-form" action="/logout" method="POST" style="display: none;">
    <input type="hidden" name="_token" :value="csrf">
</form>
```

Now add `csrf` variable inside **script** at the vue file, like this. (Remember, it must be inside **data**).

```
<script>
     export default {
        data: () => ({
            csrf: document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').getAttribute('content'),
          }),        
    }
</script>
```

**N.B.** You will see a meta tag in your `blade.php` file like this.

```
<!-- CSRF Token -->
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

If there is nothing like this, you need to place it there.

Comment: I'm currently using this approach and my token is loaded _on every page_ but for some reason I see errors in Bugsnag that my JS doesn't seem to always find the csrf-token meta tag.

Comment: This doesn't work if you aren't serving any HTML from Laravel in the first place.

Answer (score 16):

A better way is simply to pass the csrf token via a slot into the vue component.

In blade.php file:

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
          <my-vue-component>
            {{ csrf_field() }}
          </my-vue-component>
@endsection
```

In MyVueComponent.vue

```
   <form role="form">
       <slot>
         <!-- CSRF gets injected into this slot -->
       </slot> 
       <!-- form fields here -->
    </form>
```

Comment: This doesn't work if you aren't serving any HTML from Laravel in the first place.

Answer (score 3):

My solution to this is that all vue components get csrf token right before a request is made. I put this in my bootstrap.js file.

```
Vue.http.interceptors.push((request, next) => {
   request.headers.set('X-CSRF-TOKEN', CoolApp.csrfToken);
   next();
});
```

Then have a class CoolApp.php

```
    public function getScriptVariables()
    {
      return json_encode([
          'csrfToken' => csrf_token(),
      ]);
    }
```

Comment: This would be the cleanest way of doing it if you switched `CoolApp.csrfToken;` for `document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').getAttribute('content')`

Answer (score 2):

Simply, I would suggest to put this in your PHP file:

```
<script>
    window.Laravel = <?php echo json_encode(['csrfToken' => csrf_token()]); ?>
</script>
```

This way you're able to easily import your csrfToken from the JS part (Vue in this case).

Moreover, if you insert this code in your PHP layout file, you can use the token by any component of your app, since `window` is a JS global variable.

Source: I got the trick from [this](https://appdividend.com/2017/08/05/laravel-vuejs-tutorial/) post.

Comment: This answer works, and is documented but I think the question is implying without a backend serving the Vue.app. For me this answer is not useful for SPAs that are run on Cloud storage/S3.

Comment: Or are served from Nuxt.

Answer (score 2):

In case you're using **Axios**, you can do this easily by:
**Automatic Axios CSRF token attaching Solution:**

first, store the token in an HTML meta tag:

`<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">`

Then register the CSRF Token as a common header with Axios so that all outgoing HTTP requests automatically have it attached.

Inside your bootstrapping/main JS file, include:

```
let token = document.head.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]');

if (token) {
    window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-CSRF-TOKEN'] = token.content;
} else {
    console.error('CSRF token not found: https://laravel.com/docs/csrf#csrf-x-csrf-token');
}
```

Now you can make requests with csrf attached.