# Vue js post request with laravel getting 419 error and unhandled promise exception

Tags: laravel, vuejs2

My cors is set and i can also see bearer token when i make request  but i m unable to sort out what is the issue in my code or which thing is missing whenever i make post request i get unhandled promise exception with status 419 please help me guys thank you.

```
    updateuser() {   
    var data={
    username:this.firstname,
    lastname:this.lastname,
    email:this.email,
    role:this.role,
    status:this.status
    }
    this.$http.post('users/update',data).then(function(response){
    this.$router.go()
  })
  .catch(error => {
  console.log(error)
 });
```

Comment: you're just  missing the 'X-CSRF-Token' in your post.

Comment: my laravel and vue js project both are in seperate folder how can i add X-CSRF-Token in vue js is there any way?

Comment: Not so difficult https://stackoverflow.com/a/49181947/1076753 ;)

Comment: Actually those all examples are running inside laravel folder and my vue project is seperated from laravel folder so i can't use csrf_token or call it

Comment: What do you mean with "folder"? Are you using your component in a laravel/blade page or not?

Comment: No my component is inside ".vue" file it's in another directory.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190453/discussion-between-vixed-and-iqbal-butt).