# $page.props.csrf_token is undefiend (inertiajs)

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, laravel-8, inertiajs

i want to logout the user to NON inertia url. so i have to pass the `csrf token` to a form with post methd.

```
<!-- Authentication -->
<form
    method="POST"
    :action="route('logout')"
>
    <input type="hidden" name="_token" :value="$page.props.csrf_token">
    <jet-dropdown-link
        colors="text-red-700 focus:bg-gray-200 hover:bg-gray-200"
        as="button"
    >
        logout
    </jet-dropdown-link>
</form>
```

but it gives me a `419 page expired` response.

when i `console.log("this.$page.props.csrf_token")` it shows `undefined`.

what should i do?

Comment: For anyone with the same issue, read https://github.com/inertiajs/pingcrm/issues/32#issuecomment-517950878 as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it was my bad sorry. i should have read the documentation carefully.

so you can share the token with inertia middleware.

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

class HandleInertiaRequests extends Middleware
{
    public function share(Request $request)
    {
        return array_merge(parent::share($request), [
            'csrf' => csrf_token(),
        ]);
    }
}
```

and then in inertia compenents access it throught:

```
this.$page.props.csrf
```

[source](https://inertiajs.com/csrf-protection)

Answer (score 1):

You need to add @csrf under your "<form" and add

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

in  of your layout

Comment: i have it `<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">` on header of my app layout.

Comment: it's `vue.js` template not a `blade` template

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39938284/how-to-pass-laravel-csrf-token-value-to-vue/49181947#49181947

Comment: nice. thanks. but what about this: https://inertiajs.com/csrf-protection

Comment: so it was my bad. i didn't read the docmentation just looked at the code and tried it.

Comment: i suggested an edit why you are not responding?

Answer (score 1):

the simplest way is using `csrf_field`:

```
<form>
    {{ @csrf_field() }}
    <!-- other fields -->
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else who needs to find a way to pass the csrf token to inertia, one use case I have specifically is the need to have an export csv file button that sends an actual, non-AJAX HTTP request - so cant rely on axios' auto csrf feature - so I can return a file download.. what I did was in my controller where I populate $page.props, you can set an attribute to the value of the method 'csrf_token()'.. so -

Inertia::render( 'VueComponent', [ 'attribute_name' => csrf_token() ]);