# Laravel 5 TokenMismatchException

Tags: php, authentication, laravel-5, token

I know that this is an issue largely discussed and I have read a lot of posts about this but cannot find a solution.

I have developed a site locally on my PC and everything runs beautifully. I then put the site on my personal site to see how it would function. Upon doing this everything seemed to work except the Authentication part of my site. When I try to log in to my application I receive this error `TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 46`

I did not get this error locally but receive it when it is on my host server. Is there something I missed? need to change in a config file?

I have updated my .env, app.php, database.php files to run with my personal site. I made sure that this `<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">` element was right under my `<form>` tag as seen from other posts with this similar problem.

Ideas?

HTML:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" action="">
    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

Comment: Try to clear your cache, then run `php artisan key:generate`, and make sure the generated key is placed in your .env file.

Comment: @MinaYoussef Your suggestion seemed to work perfect for me. Please create a new answer so that I may select it as correct. Thank you very much for your help

Comment: Oh I am glad it worked, I have created the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to perform the following:

1. Clear your cache
2. Run `php artisan key:generate`
3. Make sure the generated key is placed in your `.env` file.

Answer (score 0):

If You are posting form using jquery then you should include csrf_token()

```
$_token = "{{ csrf_token() }}";
$.post( 'myurl', { param1: $param1, param2: $param2, _token: $_token })
.done(function( data )
{
     console.log('Done!');
});
```

And if you are posting the form directly and facing the same problem then goto app/Http/Resquests/Kernel.php and comment this line

```
\App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class
```

Answer (score 0):

See this answer and avoid doing what suggested above all the time.

[jQuery add CSRF token to all $.post() requests' data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28417781/jquery-add-csrf-token-to-all-post-requests-data)

Comment: I am not using jQuery though. Unless Laravel does this behind the scenes?

Comment: Oh sorry, got caught up in the other answer. No laravel does not use jquery.  Your field seems to be ok. You could try to use {{ crsf_field() }} instead of the input. This will create the whole input field.

Comment: so instead of `<input blah='' blah=''` put `{{ crsf_field() }}` this threw a new error for me