# call to api via http client shows error Missing CSRF token cookie

Tags: cakephp

I am making a call using cakephp's http client to an api url via post method with few parameters as json. The receiving end generates error

> Missing CSRF token cookie

Tried to search but was not able to find exact info, I am not using ajax its a direct http call.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [POST Requests for CakePHP 3 API are not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51931406/post-requests-for-cakephp-3-api-are-not-working)

Comment: it seems similar but not exactly, I was not able to find the exact piece of code / function which can be used to add CSRF Token cookie in order to associate with http.post() request. Tried using different combinations of cookies / collection object but was not successful. Can you please share more details on,,, how to figure out the way to serve the cookies ?