# Http Responding 403 Forbidden just in Post Request in GET request is ok

Tags: rest, api, cakephp-3.x, html-post

I have
public function `reciveNotification()`
and it is alowded as following

```
$this->Auth->allow([“reciveNotification”]);
```

When I do GET Request it working good but by POST request I am facing to 403 Forbidden
what am I doing wrong?

```
GET:
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Wed, 24 Apr 2019 11:06:43 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu)
Content-Length: 0
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

POST:
HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
Date: Wed, 24 Apr 2019 11:05:52 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu)
Content-Length: 836
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

Comment: Enable debug mode and check the error logs. Also those quotes aren't valid.

Comment: I have tried to turn off debug and i got
Missing CSRF token cookie

Comment: There you go... if your API doesn't require CSRF protection (which is likely), then you'll have to disable it (possibly only partially if your app isn't API only), see **https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51931406/post-requests-for-cakephp-3-api-are-not-working**.