# CakePHP 3.6 - How to get DebugKit to work with Authorization plugin?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I have a Cakephp 3.6.13 project with the DebugKit (3.16.5) and Authorization (1.0.0) plugins enabled (and Authentication 1.0.1 plugin).

The DebugKit bar doesn't load in development, with the server returning: "*The request to `/debug-kit/toolbar/5b7dae82-9c94-48df-a16b-fbf13bd97045` did not apply any authorization checks.*" which makes sense, but how do I get requests to DebugKit to pass authorization whitout affecting authorization for the rest of the site?

Using the [RequestPolicy example](https://github.com/cakephp/authorization/blob/master/docs/Request-Authorization-Middleware.md) works for plugin === DebugKit requests, but then my public actions (defined with skipAuthorization) aren't authorized anymore or, more precisely, I don't know how to Authorize them.

Comment: One option might be to apply the middleware on routing scopes, or conditionally, similar to this: **https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47714940/cakephp-3-5-6-disable-csrf-middleware-for-controller/47718018#47718018**.

Comment: Conditionnaly adding the Authorization Middleware worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As ndm suggested, I conditionally added the Authorization Middleware when the request was not for the DebugKit plugin. I added this to my Application.php middleware function :

```
$auth = new AuthorizationMiddleware($this);
$middlewareQueue
    ->add(function (ServerRequestInterface $request, ResponseInterface $response, callable $next) use ($auth) {
        if ($request->getParam('plugin') !== 'DebugKit') {
            return $auth($request, $response, $next);
        }
        return $next($request, $response);
    });
```

Not sure if this is the recommended way, but it seems to be working.

Comment: Documentation mentions this config as the appropriate way: `Configure::write('DebugKit.ignoreAuthorization', true);`

Comment: @Yevgeniy That's true, but it doesn't work for me, at least in CakePHP v4.

Answer (score 4):

Using CakePHP 4.1 adding the following config option to app_local.php will cause DebugKit to bypass policies and function normally:

```php
    'DebugKit' => [
        'ignoreAuthorization' => true
    ],
```

Comment: this is the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

I am using CakePHP 4.3 and adding the following config, similar suggested by user15008557, to **app.php** works for me.
DebugKit can now bypass Authorization policies and function normally:

```
'DebugKit' => [
        'ignoreAuthorization' => true
    ],
```