# Cakephp - CSRF token mismatch

Tags: php, ajax, cakephp, csrf, cakephp-3.x

I have a project in Cakephp 3.6 in which 3 actions in MessageController are called by Ajax. I have a problem, however, when I send a request to one of the action, XHR returns to me this:

```
{
   "message": "CSRF token mismatch.",
   "url": "\/messages\/changepriority\/8",
   "code": 403,
   "file": "D:\\xampp\\htdocs\\myapp\\vendor\\cakephp\\cakephp\\src\\Http\\Middleware\\CsrfProtectionMiddleware.php",
"line": 195
}
```

This is one of the action what I try to call from Ajax:

```
public function changepriority($id=null) 
{
    $this->autoRender = false;
    $message = $this->Messages->get($id);
    $message->priority = ($message->priority === false) ? true : false;
    if ($this->Messages->save($message)) {
        echo json_encode($message);
    }
}
```

And this is my ajax:

```
$(".email-star").click(function(){
        var idmessage = this.id;
        $.ajax({
        headers : {
              'X-CSRF-Token': $('[name="_csrfToken"]').val()
           },
         dataType: "json",
         type: "POST",
         evalScripts: true,
         async:true,
         url: '<?php echo Router::url(array('controller'=>'Messages','action'=>'changepriority'));?>' +'/'+idmessage,
         success: function(data){
            if(data['priority'] === false) {
                $("#imp_" + idmessage).removeClass("fas").removeClass('full-star').addClass( "far" );
            }
            else {
                $("#imp_" + idmessage).removeClass("far").addClass( "fas" ).addClass("full-star");
            }
          }
         });
    });
```

I have read the documentation about Cross Site Request Forgery, and I tried to turn off the Csrf for these action first with:

```
public function beforeFilter(Event $event)
{
     $this->getEventManager()->off($this->Csrf);
}
```

and then with:

```
public function beforeFilter(Event $event)
{
     $this->Security->setConfig('unlockedActions', ['index', 'changepriority']);
}
```

But nothing. The Xhr return always the CSRF token mismatch.
What can I do ?

**Edit:**

I change the action in this way:

```
    public function changepriority($id=null) 
{
    $this->autoRender = false;
    $message = $this->Messages->get($id);
    $message->priority = ($message->priority === false) ? true : false;
    if ($this->Messages->save($message)) {
        $content = json_encode($message);
        $this->response->getBody()->write($content);
        $this->response = $this->response->withType('json');
        return $this->response;
    }
}
```

In that way the action works. Can it be like that?

Comment: On an unrelated note, [**controlls should _never_ echo data**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42378793/how-to-output-custom-http-body-contents-with-cakephp-3-4-echoing-causes-unable/42379581#42379581)!

Comment: The solution you send to me work, but Is there any way to send a csrf parameter to the controller without using a form?

Comment: Yes, see [**my comment**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51741264/cakephp-csrf-token-mismatch?noredirect=1#comment90445318_51741757) to D3ad L0cKs answer.

Comment: Yes, I've seen the comment, but I do not really understand how to do it

Comment: You just need to replace `$(...).val()` with the `<?= json_encode(...); ?>` example.

Comment: Yes, it's work! Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 1):

First check your `$('[name="_csrfToken"]').val()` output.

If you didn't get any output, need to check `csrfToken` hidden field is exist or not. Just right click in your page and click `View Page Source`

If not exist, you don't follow proper way when you create Form. Basically, when forms are created with the `Cake\View\Helper\FormHelper`, a hidden field is added containing the CSRF token.

If everything is correct, add the following line inside your ajax call after `header`

```
beforeSend: function (xhr) {
    xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token', $('[name="_csrfToken"]').val());
},
```

Ps. Disabling the CSRF is not recommended by cakePHP and most of the developer aware of this. Hope this help.

Comment: Side note, there's usually no need for a form, as [**the current CSRF token can be read from the request object**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44454785/how-to-define-csrf-token-in-ajax-call-in-cakephp-3-also-how-csrf-can-be-off-for/44455396#44455396).

Answer (score 0):

```
beforeSend: function (xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token', <?= json_encode($this->request->getAttribute('csrfToken')) ?>);
    },
```