# How to add Django's CSRF token to the header of a jQuery POST request?

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, django-csrf

I'm trying to make a Django form with dynamically pre-populated fields: that is, when one field (`checkin_type`) gets selected from a drop-down menu, other fields get automatically pre-populated with corresponding data. To this end, I would like to send a POST request to the server as soon as a drop-down option is selected.

So far I've tried the following template (following https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/csrf/):

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/js-cookie@2/src/js.cookie.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var csrftoken = Cookies.get('csrftoken');

        $(".auto-submit").change(function() {
            $.post({
                url: "{% url 'get-checkin-type' %}",
                data: $(".auto-submit option:selected").val(),
                headers: {
                    X-CSRFToken: csrftoken
                }
            })
        });
    });
</script>


<form action="" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    {% for field in form %}
        <div class="{% if field.name == 'checkin_type' %}auto-submit{% endif %}">
            {{ field.errors }}
            {{ field.label_tag }}
            {{ field }}
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
    <input type="submit" value="Send message" />
</form>
```

However, when I select a drop-down option I get a

> new:17 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token -

which emanates from the `X-CSRFToken: csrftoken` line:

[image]

Can someone point out to me what is wrong with this code? (I tried looking it up from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Unexpected_token but so far couldn't figure it out).

By the way, it seems from [jQuery add CSRF token to all $.post() requests' data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28417781/jquery-add-csrf-token-to-all-post-requests-data) that one can also add the CSRF token to the POST request's `data`, but this doesn't seem like the most elegant approach to me, and the docs state that

> For this reason, there is an alternative method: on each XMLHttpRequest, set a custom **X-CSRFToken** header to the value of the CSRF token.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing single quote, Try like following.

```
$(".auto-submit").change(function() {
    $.post({
        url: "{% url 'get-checkin-type' %}",
        data: $(".auto-submit option:selected").val(),
        headers: {
            'X-CSRFToken': csrftoken
        }
    })
});
```

Answer (score 3):

[PSK](https://stackoverflow.com/users/297322/psk)'s solution works, but for the sake of completeness, here is the approach as outlined by the Django docs after reading a bit further (from https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/csrf/#setting-the-token-on-the-ajax-request) which uses a `.ajaxSetup` to cover all requests once and for all:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/js-cookie@2/src/js.cookie.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var csrftoken = Cookies.get('csrftoken');

        function csrfSafeMethod(method) {
            // these HTTP methods do not require CSRF protection
            return (/^(GET|HEAD|OPTIONS|TRACE)$/.test(method));
        }
        $.ajaxSetup({
            beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
                if (!csrfSafeMethod(settings.type) && !this.crossDomain) {
                    xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
                }
            }
        });

        $(".auto-submit").change(function() {
            $.post({
                url: "{% url 'get-checkin-type' %}",
                data: $(".auto-submit option:selected").val(),
            })
        });
    });
</script>
```